# How to decode an image sent from a server to Flutter application?

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I am sending my json response from the serve to my Flutter Application. The API deals with fetching an image from mobile to server and detects the object.
After detection, the response body sent from the server is an image which has annotations for the class detected in the image. 
I am sending it an encoded image file which is encoded with the help of toString(). 
Server-side Code:

```
import time
from absl import app, logging
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from yolov3_tf2.models import (
    YoloV3, YoloV3Tiny
)
from yolov3_tf2.dataset import transform_images, load_tfrecord_dataset
from yolov3_tf2.utils import draw_outputs
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify, send_from_directory, abort
import os

# customize your API through the following parameters
classes_path = './data/labels/obj.names'
weights_path = './weights/yolov3-tiny.tf'
tiny = True                    # set to True if using a Yolov3 Tiny model
size = 416                      # size images are resized to for model
output_path = './detections/'   # path to output folder where images with detections are saved
num_classes = 1               # number of classes in model

# load in weights and classes
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

if tiny:
    yolo = YoloV3Tiny(classes=num_classes)
else:
    yolo = YoloV3(classes=num_classes)

yolo.load_weights(weights_path).expect_partial()
print('weights loaded')

class_names = [c.strip() for c in open(classes_path).readlines()]
print('classes loaded')

# Initialize Flask application
app = Flask(_name_)

# API that returns image with detections on it
@app.route('/image', methods= ['POST'])
def get_image():
    image = request.files["images"]
    image_name = image.filename
    image.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_name))
    img_raw = tf.image.decode_image(
        open(image_name, 'rb').read(), channels=3)
    img = tf.expand_dims(img_raw, 0)
    img = transform_images(img, size)

    t1 = time.time()
    boxes, scores, classes, nums = yolo(img)
    t2 = time.time()
    print('time: {}'.format(t2 - t1))

    print('detections:')
    for i in range(nums[0]):
        print('\t{}, {}, {}'.format(class_names[int(classes[0][i])],
                                        np.array(scores[0][i]),
                                        np.array(boxes[0][i])))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img_raw.numpy(), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    img = draw_outputs(img, (boxes, scores, classes, nums), class_names)
    cv2.imwrite(output_path + 'detection.jpg', img)
    print('output saved to: {}'.format(output_path + 'detection.jpg'))

    # prepare image for response
    _, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
    response = img_encoded.tostring()
    #remove temporary image
    os.remove(image_name)

    try:
        return Response(response=response, status=200, mimetype='image/jpg') 
    except FileNotFoundError:
        abort(404)
if _name_ == '_main_':
    app.run(debug=True, host = '0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Client-side code

```
final String url_API = "http://18b8b114.ngrok.io/image";                       //Post the image to the Object detection API for classification                                               Future <Response> dio_upload(String imagePath) async {  

      http.MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url_API));
      request.files.add(
      await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'images',
      image.path,
      contentType: MediaType('application', 'jpeg'),
    ),
  );

  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
  print(response.statusCode);
  print(await response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).join());
```

The last print statement thorws an error stating Bad UTF string. In what form should I decode the response? This is the only known code to me with MultipartRequest.

Comment: sent the URL of the image through API, then you can simply fetch the image independently using that URL

Comment: Sending the URL from the application to server, which means you are telling him to store the image in firebase and then send the image url! But what if his code is optimized to work with sending images directly and getting a response for the image sent? Because that's what his server side code does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well creating a static_url_path and access the image will do the job pretty easily.

```
 app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
```

Also creating a route that send from a directory also works perfectly.

```
@app.route('/result')
def send_js():
    return send_from_directory('static/images', 'detection.jpg')
```

Then simply using NetworkImage in flutter can help get the image :)